# C++11 Regex Capture Groups By Name

Tags: regex, c++11, capture-group

I am converting my boost-based regular expressions to C++11 regex. I have a capture group called `url`:

```
\s*?=\s*?(("(?<url>.*?)")|('?<url>.*?)'))
```

With boost, if you had an `smatch` you could call `match.str("url")` to get the capture group by name. With `std::smatch`, I am only seeing indexed sub-matches.

How can I get access to the url capture using the std::smatch class?

Comment: Have you tried `(?P<url>.*?)` instead of `(?<url>.*?)` ?

Comment: @HamZa I am not sure if C++11 regex supports named capture groups. I just read the entire chapter dedicated to the topic in Stroustrup's new "The C++ Programming Language" and it doesn't even mention it. And many of the online references don't seem to indicate otherwise.

Comment: It seems it doesn't support named groups according to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6398650).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot name a capture group with the c++11 standard. C++11 regex conforms to the ECMAScript syntax. Here is a link that explains it all http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/. Even though this maybe disappointing if you think about it a true regular expression will not support this it is extra.

Comment: Can you post an example extracting a nested group? Perhaps where the match can be on either side of a pipe?

Comment: I basically want to see how to efficiently extract my url based on my posted example, updated to not rely on named capture groups.

Comment: This makes me sad!