# Group last segment of a path using RegEx

Tags: c++, regex

I have a path where the first segments in this path are constant and will never change, the last segment is variable.

Example:

```
/my/awesome/path
/my/awesome/path/
/my/awesome/path/1
/my/awesome/path/2
```

Is it possible using regex to determine the last segment and group it to a certain name?
For example group it to name: **id**

So the match would be:

```
1. id=""
2. id=""
3. id="1"
4. id="2"
```

Comment: Do you really need regex for this? Couldn't you strip the known prefix(es) and have your answer? e.g. pseudo-code `id = url.stripLeft("/my/awesome/path").stripLeft("/")`

Comment: Unfortunately I do. Because this is just the base for a specific use case to fulfill.

Comment: But why does this use-case _require_ a regex? Why can't it be fulfilled through other means?

Comment: This is just a very simple example of the real use-case. My hope is to avoid big if/else constructs in my code to realize this. Maybe RegEx can do this job for me in an efficient way.

Comment: In that case, please give an example that is closer to your real use case. Right now, I don't see how a RegEx would simplify or is even required. Also, no big if/else constructs are required (as can seen by the pseudo code). You might even achieve your result by splitting the string, removing the first N parts and then read your id. https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: Also, you haven't mentioned which regex dialect you can use (or in which programming language your regex engine is implemented)

Comment: Let's suppose we have a hash-table. The key in this table can look like "/my/path/:id", where :id represent the variable part. If now any pathname comes in, f.e. "/my/path/1" I want to verify whether this path matches to the key in my hash-table and which value contains the variable segment of my path. Maybe RegEx isn't the best tool to achieve this. I don't know.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to perform path matching similar to how the [AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) works. I'm pretty sure there exist similar implementations for C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely, 100% must use a regex, here's one possible solution which should work with most regex engines:

```
^/my/awesome/path/?(.*)$
```

The first capturing group will contain your id after the known prefix (with our without slash).

Comment: This looks good, but can I give the first group a name?

Comment: What do you mean? The first group is called `1`. Naming groups looks different, depending on the regex engine and some do not support it at all.

Comment: In C++ the ECMAScript is used. Giving the capturing group a name is just a gold frame and not really necessary. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @Dirk [Named capturing groups are not supported by C++ 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16888480/112968)

Comment: Not supported? That was unexpected. tyvm